# Set Text from String to Decimal Format

Tags: java, android, string, settext

Simple i wanna make my output (TextView ) from String like Rp.40000 to be Rp.40.000

here is my code :

```
 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_detail);
    //Mengambil data dari intent
    DecimalFormat formatter = new DecimalFormat("#,###,###");
    Intent i=getIntent();
    String npwp = i.getStringExtra(TAG_NPWP);
    String statusspp = i.getStringExtra(TAG_STATUSSPP);
    String tglsp2d= i.getStringExtra(TAG_TGLSP2D);
    String jumlahtotal = i.getStringExtra(TAG_JUMLAH);
    TextView textName=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textName);
    TextView textLat=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textLat);
    TextView textLon=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textLon);
    TextView textPrice=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textPrice);
    textName.setText("Nama : "+npwp);
    textLat.setText(statusspp);
    textLon.setText("TglSp2D : "+tglsp2d);
    textPrice.setText("Jumlah : Rp "+jumlahtotal);
```

Comment: What is your question. didn't understood? Edit your quetion.

Comment: @RizkiDeddySusanto, it seems you are never using your formatter.

Comment: `textPrice.setText("Jumlah : Rp "+ formatter.format(jumlahtotal));`

Comment: you can use NumberFormat.getInstance().format(longNumber)

Comment: if you have a String like Rp.40000 and want to add a decimal, copy the String into a empty string char by char. Then when you reach the point you want to add the decimal add it. Then print the new string

Comment: Use `java.util.Currency`, creating from `new Locale("in", "ID")`, and then follow the currency formatting example at https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/format/numberFormat.html

Comment: Sorry, i mean : i wanna make my output textview (TextPrice ) from String like Rp.40000 to be Rp.40.000 in a string "jumlahtotal"

Answer (score 1):

I hope this helps:

```
NumberFormat numberFormatter = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(new Locale("in", "ID"));
textPrice.setText("Jumlah : "+ numberFormatter.format(40000));
```

Instead of `40000` pass the number you wanna format.

**EDIT: If the value you have is a string, and it is a valid number:**

```
NumberFormat numberFormatter = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(new Locale("in", "ID"));
Double number = Double.parseDouble(yourString);
textPrice.setText("Jumlah : "+ numberFormatter.format(number));
```

Comment: how about the value is string from JSON (jumlahtotal is value)

Comment: @RizkiDeddySusanto, I have edited my answer, so I hope this helps.

Comment: a pleasure @RizkiDeddySusanto, please do not forget to validate this answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

> DecimalFormatSymbols.setGroupingSeperator

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int val = 40000;
    DecimalFormatSymbols dfs = DecimalFormatSymbols.getInstance();
    dfs.setGroupingSeparator('.');
    DecimalFormat formatter = new DecimalFormat("#,###",dfs);
    System.out.println(formatter.format(val));
}
```